# Who is the author of this quote about saying the right words on a mountaintop and changing the world?

Tags: quote-source

I have a recollection of a quote I thought came from Heinrich Heine. My recollection of the quote is something like this:

> If you go up to the mountaintop and say the right words, the whole world will change.

The word mountaintop is popular in quotes but I don’t find anything resembling my quote in Google searches, so there is probably something wrong with my recollection.
Does anyone recognize the quote which sounds like a German romantic literary product?

Comment: I don't know where that quote is from, but I wonder if it is a reference to Dr Martin Luther King Jnr. He made a speech in Memphis, Tenn. which repeatedly uses the refrain 'I've been to the mountaintop' in reference to Mount Olympus and the classical philosophers. Dr King's words also went a long way towards changing the world. http://kingencyclopedia.stanford.edu/encyclopedia/documentsentry/ive_been_to_the_mountaintop/ The speech rewards the reading.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Nietzsche had a quote “All I need is a sheet of paper and something to write with, and then I can turn the world upside down”, which seems to be more about his personal power. I believe I thought at the moment I first saw the quote I look for, that it was more about mystical power hidden in the words. That is why I thought it was 19 century romantic (perhaps German).

Comment: TBH, the quote sounds like a bit of a mash up of the two things to me. Many 'quotes' that drift around cyber space are half-remembered, mis-reconstructed amalgams.

Comment: @MikaelJensen That Nietzche quote sounds like a reference to Archimedes' line, "Give me the place to stand, and I shall move the earth" as per https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Archimedes

Comment: This experience has led me to believe that it may have been a passage in a less famous text. Thanks to all of you.